# Jquery Ajax not sending through to php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have tried many thing but cannot get this to work. The variables that are passed to the ajax code 100% have string within them. I have tested the code bit by bit until the ajax code and after. Everything before proves that the variables do no get 'lost' they display the correct values. I even tried a simple "test" string without using ANY other data to be sent through ajax. Still no data gets received by the PHP code.
Based on my test literally no POST data is being passed through to the PHP script. 
The php script is on the same page.
The page is called slate_designer.php

jquery:

```
$('#submit').on('click', function () {
var firstname = $('#firstname').val();
var lastname = $('#lastname').val();
var email = $('#email').val();
var tel = $('#tel').val();
    var slate = $( '#slate' ).html();

    var dataToSend = {
    "firstname" : firstname,
    "lastname" : lastname
};

var serialized = dataToSend.serialize();

$.ajax({
        url: 'slate_designer.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType:'json',
        data: serialized 
    });
```

php:

```
if(isset($_POST["firstname"])){
$firstname = $_POST["firstname"];
$lastname = $_POST["lastname"];
$email_address = $_POST["email"];
$phone_num = $_POST["tel"];
$comment = $_POST["comment"];
$slate = $_POST["slate"];

$header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\n";
$headers .= "From:" . $email_address;
$headers .= "To: sergey95@gmail.com";

$message = "";
$message = "Name: " . $firstname . " " . $lastname . "\n";
$message .= "Email: " . $email_address . "\n";
$message .= "Phone Number: " . $phone_num . "\n";
$message .= "Message: " . $comment . "\n";
$message .= "Slate: \n" . $slate . "\n"; 


$to = 'email@gmail.com';
$subject = 'Order';

wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message );
```

Comment: `serialize()` is used on form elements, not  on object literals. Read the docs http://api.jquery.com/serialize/ then read the `$.ajax` docs to see how to pass data

Comment: I dont think you need to use `serialize()`. `data: dataToSend` should suffice. Also, if you're using Chrome, you should open then **dev tools** and check the `network` tab, that will give you the `form data` on your request (I believe Firefox has about the same tools).

Comment: I deleted the serialize and deleted the URL as the ajax call is to the php in the same file and it works now!